# Rewrite not functioning in httpd.conf

Tags: mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

My `httpd.conf` has:

```
<Directory "/var/www/site">
    AllowOverride All

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.com [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.site.com/$1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://www.site.com/$1

    Allow from all
    SetEnv ENV production
</Directory>
```

I want to redirect all non-www to www and everything to https.

But this seems to do nothing

Comment: I would suggest you add the rules to the server context, and not a directory context. Furthermore you are probably better of by having a general redirect in your http virtual host to the https host. Lastly: Enable rewrite log. That will tell you tons about how the rules are applied